# why is sudo not working with exported path?

Tags: sudo, paths, gksudo

If not sure if this is close to (or even a duplicate of) [Why does sudo not add root's PATH with Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146869/why-does-sudo-not-add-roots-path-with-ubuntu-12-04), I'm still posting this question because I didn't understand anything from there, if this is a duplicate, please do not flag it as that, just explain it better than that question, or post another answer in the other question.

I installed ISE from Xilinx. I was advised to export the path, which I did by entering

```
echo "PATH=\$PATH:/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/" >> ~/.bashrc
```

then

```
echo "export PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

That done, I can run then program by entering `ise` in a terminal, but if I enter `sudo ise` it won't work. I'm I forgetting something?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` overwrites the path for security reasons with a "secure" path. However you can modify this secure path to include your custom folder. **Warning: this leaves your computer a bit unprotected.** You can follow these steps for edit the secure path.

- Execute the command `sudo visudo` for edit `/etc/sudoers`
- Find this line (it should be at the start of the file):

  ```
  Defaults       secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
  ```
- If do you want to include your custom path here, edit the `secure_path` variable. It would look like this:

  ```
  Defaults       secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/"
  ```
- If do you want to bypass completely this security measure **(not recommended)**, simply comment out that line. It will allow the `$PATH` variable to "pass" through the `sudo` command

Comment: Before I do anything, would you please explain how unprotected I am when using the command (not commenting the full line)?

Comment: `sudo` overrides the path to include only the locations that seems to be safe (paths with root as owner and only read and execute permission for group and others) by this way, I can't overwrite a program without permission, because is on a path owned by me (i.e. What happens if I change `cat` or `grep` by `rm`). However, I think that it will not happen (there are only a few rootkits for Linux). I have a 7 years experience with Linux and nothing happened.